Why is virtual thread on java is set as daemon?
In JEP 444, I could see the following:

Virtual threads are always daemon threads. The Thread.setDaemon(boolean) method cannot change a virtual thread to be a non-daemon thread.

But what is the reason behind it? As per my understanding , you will mark those Threads daemon whose completion you do not always care. Therefore, does it mean you should use virtual thread only if you do not care it's completion ( I do not think so :) )?

"Daemon threads are threads whose completion you do not always care" - if you mean "completion before shutdown of JVM", then yes.

Quite simply, virtual threads are not real, honest-to-goodness threads by definition.  Yes, you'd only use them when you don't care about a thread's exit status.  (Note, the times you actually do -- or should -- care about the thread rather than the work, are few and far between.)

I changed your mention and link from an old preview JEP to the final release JEP 444. Also, note that Stark Overflow offers Markdown for quotations. I edited your prose to make a formal quotation.

Note nothing prevents you from using a single non-daemon platform thread to wait for a set of tasks being executed by virtual threads to complete.

I think that the main concern is that you do not want to make tracking of virtual threads mandatory (to detect whether the JVM should terminate), as virtual threads ought to be created and destroyed cheaply, potentially in large numbers. By defining all virtual threads as daemon threads, the JVM only has to check whether there are non-daemon platform threads alive.
